# how can I ignore duplicate inserts?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I basically have the same question posed here - [Optimal way to ignore duplicate inserts?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30499/optimal-way-to-ignore-duplicate-inserts) - except in my case it's SQL Server.

I have a table that is a list of person IDs who are deceased.  There are many places in the source database that a person can be indicated as deceased.  I would like to do INSERTS from each of these locations into this main table, but a person may be indicated as deceased in multiple places.

Ideally (I think) I just want to ignore duplicate key errors - in the most efficient way possible.  (Thus I don't want to have to check the main table for the IDs as part of my INSERT statement.)

(related to solving my question [need suggestions to improve view performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30592/need-suggestions-to-improve-view-performance))

Comment: Is this a one-time operation?  If not, will you use a stored procedure or anything else?

Comment: Ongoing operation - and can be part of a stored procedure.

Comment: Without the check, how do you want to ignore duplicates?  Either way yo go, somewhere you _have to_ check.

Comment: I didn't think this through thoroughly - I can catch this in the stored procedure.  I shall answer my own question shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this lies in the table creation itself.  If I set `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` on the index on my person ID column, the duplicate values are simply ignored and the rest are inserted appropriately.

Comment: Isn't `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` a property of an index rather than a property of a column?

Comment: excellent point - modified accordingly

Comment: I hope the source data is clean enough that you know the duplicates will *always* contain the same version of the truth... This can be a really dangerous way to solve the problem (in general).

Comment: Agreed, but in this case I am simply gathering Person IDs from three separate queries and inserting them into a single column table... and my logic is if they are deceased in any of three queries, they are deceased.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the EXCEPT clause in your insert statement. It will most likely be faster than the IGNORE_DUP_KEYS option. See here for details and a benchmark:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic856838-392-1.aspx

A third option is to use the MERGE command.

A fourth option is to use the where not in trick

Answer (score 1):

I have used a merge statement to do this in the following format:

```
merge into [dbo].[table]
using [dbo].[Stage_Table] on Stage_Table.pk = table.pk
when not matched then insert (val1) values (1234);
```

Re-reading your question, this probably wouldn't have efficiency you are looking for, but may be useful information for other readers.